# Why does convertng to Constraint Layout distort view

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

My original `layout` was code as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.Camera.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/textureView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/photo_thumbnail_recyclerview"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="snap"
    android:id="@+id/snap"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The textureView takes up a sizable amount of the fragment. When I switch to having a Constraint Layout as shown in the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.Camera.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/textureView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/photo_thumbnail_recyclerview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/photo_thumbnail_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/switchcamera_imageButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textureView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_switch_camera_white_24px" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/takepicture_imageButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textureView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_white_24px" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The texture `view` only takes up the width of the parent `fragment`, which is what I want. The height, however, isn't much more than the height of the `imagebuttons` that should be located at the bottom of the `textureView`. Also, the `recyclerview` doesn't show anymore. Any have a hypothesis as to why?

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the layout i wanted, I switched from a constraintlayout to a relativelayout